# sql server Query Optimizer’s non Cluster Index selection (in case of having multiple indexes)

Tags: sql, sql-server

How SQL server Query Optimizer’s select a non cluster index , if a table have multiple non cluster indexes and same column is being used in all of them.

Comment: How optimizers use indexes is a very broad topic.  You can start with the documentation:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/2014-toc/sql-server-index-design-guide?view=sql-server-2014.

Comment: Just because a column is part of an index, it does not mean that the index will ever be used. Assuming you have code like `... WHERE DateAdded >= @dtAdded`, a nonclustered index will only be specifically chosen for this match if the `DateAdded` field was the **first** column in the index. If it is embedded somewhere in the middle of an index, such as an index by `OrderID, DateAdded desc`, the optimizer will find no reason to use this index, since a clustered index scan will be as fast or faster.

Comment: @LaughingVergil thanks for your explanation and it helped me , but i have one more question, what will the optimizer do , if two non cluster indexes started with DateAdded column